# bitnami mongodb shard timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"

Tags: mongodb, bitnami

I'm trying to start up bitnami mongodb shard but without success. On mongodb-shard0_1 I'm getting this error timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse".

On mongodb-sharded_1  has this info mongodb 16:02:57.61 INFO  ==> Found MongoDB server listening at mongodb-cfg:27017 !

I'm trying to start this configuration  https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb-sharded/blob/master/docker-compose.yml with docker-compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce the issue, in my case everything works fine by using:

```
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb-sharded/master/docker-compose.yml > docker-compose.yml
$ docker-compose up
```